# How many ways are to arrange the letters in MISSISSIPPI so that AT LEAST ONE of the following properties holds:

Tags: combinatorics

**continuing the question from:**

so that AT LEAST ONE of the following properties holds: the $4$ I's are all consecutive or the $4$ S's are all consecutive or the $2$ P's are consecutive?

The answer is supposed to be $$2 \cdot \frac{8!}{4!2!} + \frac{10!}{4!4!} - \left[2 \cdot \frac{7!}{4!}+ \frac{5!}{2!}\right]+ 4!$$

Can someone explain where is each part from?

$2 \cdot \frac{8!}{4!2!} \to 4$ I's and it's multiplied by $2$ because counting in pairs?

$\frac{10!}{4!4!} \to$ counting the M, but I'm not sure why it is $10$ factorial

$2 \cdot \frac{7!}{4!} + \frac{5!}{2!} \to$ don't understand where is the $\frac{7!}{4!}$ coming from?

$4! \to$ the $2$ P's

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to treat a block of consecutive identical letters as a single object.

Let's adopt the notation used by drhab.

Let $I$ denote the set of permutations in which the four I's are consecutive.

Let $S$ denote the set of permutations in which the four S's are consecutive.

Let $P$ denote the set of permutations in which the two P's are consecutive.

The set of arrangements of the word MISSISSIPPI in which at least one of the properties the four I's are consecutive, the four S's are consecutive, or the two P's are consecutive is $I \cup S \cup P$.  By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of such arrangements is given by the formula
$$|I \cup S \cup P| = |I| + |S| + |P| - |I \cap S| - |I \cap P| - |S \cap P| + |I \cap S \cap P|$$

$|I|$:  We treat the block of four consecutive I's as a single object.  Therefore, we have eight objects to arrange: IIII, M, S, S, S, S, P, P.  We can fill four of the eight positions with S's in $\binom{8}{4}$ ways and two of the remaining four positions with P's in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.  There are $2!$ ways to fill the remaining two positions with the distinct objects IIII and M.  Hence, 
$$|I| = \binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{2}2! = \frac{8!}{4!4!} \cdot \frac{4!}{2!2!} \cdot 2! = \frac{8!}{4!2!}$$
The factor of $4!$ in the denominator represents the number of ways the S's can be permuted among themselves without producing an arrangement distinguishable from the given arrangement.  The factor of $2!$ in the denominator represents the number of ways the P's can be permuted among themselves without producing an arrangement distinguishable from the given arrangement.

$|S|$:  We treat the block of four consecutive S's as a single object.  Again, we have eight objects to arrange:  SSSS, M, I, I, I, I, P, P.  By symmetry, there are
$$\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{2}2! = \frac{8!}{4!2!}$$
such arrangements.

$|P|$:  We treat the block of two consecutive P's as a single object.  This time we have ten objects to arrange: PP, M, I, I, I, I, S, S, S, S.  We can fill four of the ten positions with I's in $\binom{10}{4}$ ways and four of the remaining six positions with S's in $\binom{6}{4}$ ways.  The remaining two positions can be filled with the distinct objects M and PP in $2!$ ways.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{10}{4}\binom{6}{4}2! = \frac{10!}{4!4!}$$
such arrangements.

$|I \cap S|$:  We treat the block of four consecutive I's as a single object and the block of four consecutive S's as a single object.  Therefore, we have five objects to arrange:  IIII, SSSS, M, P, P.  We can choose two of the five positions for the P's in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways.  The remaining three distinct objects can be arranged in the remaining three positions in $3!$ ways.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{5}{2}3! = \frac{5!}{2!3!} \cdot 3! = \frac{5!}{2!}$$
such arrangements.

$|I \cap P|$:  We treat the block of four consecutive I's as a single object and the block of two consecutive P's as a single object.  Therefore, we have seven objects to arrange:  IIII, PP, M, S, S, S, S.  We can choose four of the seven positions for the S's in $\binom{7}{4}$ ways.  The remaining three distinct objects can be arranged in the remaining three positions in $3!$ ways.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{7}{4}3! = \frac{7!}{3!4!} \cdot 3! = \frac{7!}{4!}$$
such arrangements.

$|S \cap P|$:  We treat the block of four consecutive S's as a single object and the block of two consecutive P's as a single object.  Therefore, we have seven objects to arrange:  SSSS, PP, M, I, I, I, I.  By symmetry, there are 
$$\binom{7}{4}3! = \frac{7!}{4!}$$
such arrangements.

$|I \cap S \cap P|$:  We treat the block of four consecutive I's as a single object, the block of four consecutive S's as a single object, and the block of two consecutive P's as a single object.  Therefore, we have four objects to arrange:  IIII, SSSS, PP, M.  Since the four objects are distinct, they can be arranged in $4!$ ways.

Hence, by the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, 
\begin{align*}
|I \cup S \cup P| & = |I| + |S| + |P| - |I \cap S| - |I \cap P| - |S \cap P| + |I \cap S \cap P|\\
 & = \frac{8!}{4!2!} + \frac{8!}{4!2!} + \frac{10!}{4!4!} - \frac{5!}{2!} - \frac{7!}{4!} - \frac{7!}{4!} + 4!\\
 & = 2 \cdot \frac{8!}{4!2!} + \frac{10!}{4!4!} - \frac{5!}{2!} - 2 \cdot \frac{7!}{4!} + 4!
\end{align*}
Note that the factors of $2$ are due to symmetry:  the word MISSISSIPPI has four S's and four I's, so $|I| = |S|$ and $|I \cap P| = |S \cap P|$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ denote the set of arrangements such that the four I's are consecutive.

Let $S$ denote the set of arrangements such that the four S's are consecutive.

Let $P$ denote the set of arrangements such that the two P's are consecutive.

With the principle of inclusion/exclusion and symmetry we find:$$|I\cup S\cup P|=2|I|+|P|-|I\cap S|-2|I\cap P|+|I\cap S\cap P|$$

$|I|$ equals the number of arrangements of the letters MISSSSPP.

$|P|$ equals the number of arrangements of the letters MIIIISSSSP.

$|I\cap S|$ equals the number of arrangements of the letters MISPP.

$|I\cap P|$ equals the number of arrangements of the letters MISSSSP.

$|I\cap S\cap P|$ equals the number of arrangements of the letters MISP.

So we end up with:$$|I\cup S\cup P|=2\times\frac{8!}{1!1!4!2!}+\frac{10!}{1!4!4!1!}-\frac{5!}{1!1!1!2!}-2\times\frac{7!}{1!1!4!1!}+\frac{4!}{1!1!1!1!}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, MISSISSIPPI is word of type $1^12^43^44^2$ (M occurs 1-time, I 4-times, S 4-times, P 2-times) so that the number of words that can be formed by these letters is the multinomial coefficient (length 11)
$${11 \choose 1,4,4,2}.$$
Four consecutive I's are reached if you consider the number of words that can be formed by MSSSSPP, which has type $1^12^43^2$, i.e.,
$${7\choose 1,4,2}.$$
Then the four I's can be placed at any position (i.e., multiply by 7(length)+1). Hope it helps!

Comment: I get the first part of your explanation, but don't understand the second part. Are you explaining where the (8!/4!2!) is coming from or (7!/4!)?